# listrows.add(alwaysinsert:true) is overwriting the last row, not adding a row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a monthly workbook with data for multiple weeks. I am trying to write a macro that will go through each weeks data and look for 3 unique variables in each row. If it finds those variables, I want it to add them to a table at the end. I am using listrows.add(alwaysinsert:=true) to add the new row to the table. However, when I watch the macro run, it keeps pasting the data over the data in the last row, not adding a new row. How do I get it add the row and stop overwriting the data that is there?

```
Dim wbact As Workbook
Dim wswk As Worksheet, wsttl As Worksheet, wssu As Worksheet
Dim tblttl As ListObject
Dim tblttlrw As ListRow
Dim ttlrw As Range

Set wbact = ThisWorkbook
Set wsttl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals")
Set wssu = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Up")
Set tblttl = wsttl.ListObjects("Totals")
Set tblttlrw = tblttl.ListRows.Add(, AlwaysInsert:=True)

Dim i As Long, ytdd As Long, j As Long, lngttl As Long, ytda As Long, ytdu As Long, wk As Long, n As Long, o As Long, k As Long, l As Long
Dim strcon As String, strlstn As String, strfstn As String, att As String, strwk As String


wk = 1
n = 0

Do Until n = 6
    strwk = "Week " & wk
    Set wswk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strwk)


    For i = 6 To wswk.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If IsEmpty(wswk.Cells(i, 5)) = False And IsEmpty(wswk.Cells(i, 2)) = False And IsEmpty(wswk.Cells(i, 3)) = False Then
            strcon = wswk.Cells(i, 5).Value
            strlstn = wswk.Cells(i, 2).Value
            strfstn = wswk.Cells(i, 3).Value
            With tblttlrw
                .Range(1) = strlstn
                .Range(2) = strfstn
                .Range(3) = wswk.Cells(i, 4).Value
                .Range(4) = wssu.Cells(2, 2).Value
                .Range(5) = wssu.Cells(2, 3).Value
                .Range(6) = strcon
                .Range(7) = wswk.Cells(i, 6)
                .Range(8) = wswk.Cells(i, 7)
                .Range(9) = wswk.Cells(i, 17)
                .Range(10) = wswk.Cells(i, 19)
                .Range(11) = wswk.Cells(i, 20)
            End With
        End If
        Next i

    n = n + 1
    wk = wk + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add the new row *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
Dim wbact As Workbook
Dim wswk As Worksheet, wsttl As Worksheet, wssu As Worksheet
Dim tblttl As ListObject
Dim tblttlrw As ListRow
Dim ttlrw As Range

Set wbact = ThisWorkbook
Set wsttl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Totals")
Set wssu = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Set Up")
Set tblttl = wsttl.ListObjects("Totals")
Set tblttlrw = tblttl.ListRows.Add

Dim i As Long, ytdd As Long, j As Long, lngttl As Long, ytda As Long, ytdu As Long, wk As Long, n As Long, o As Long, k As Long, l As Long
Dim strcon As String, strlstn As String, strfstn As String, att As String, strwk As String


wk = 1
n = 0

Do Until n = 6
    strwk = "Week " & wk
    Set wswk = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strwk)


    For i = 6 To wswk.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If IsEmpty(wswk.Cells(i, 5)) = False And IsEmpty(wswk.Cells(i, 2)) = False And IsEmpty(wswk.Cells(i, 3)) = False Then
            strcon = wswk.Cells(i, 5).Value
            strlstn = wswk.Cells(i, 2).Value
            strfstn = wswk.Cells(i, 3).Value
            With tblttlrw
                .Range(1) = strlstn
                .Range(2) = strfstn
                .Range(3) = wswk.Cells(i, 4).Value
                .Range(4) = wssu.Cells(2, 2).Value
                .Range(5) = wssu.Cells(2, 3).Value
                .Range(6) = strcon
                .Range(7) = wswk.Cells(i, 6)).Value
                .Range(8) = wswk.Cells(i, 7)).Value
                .Range(9) = wswk.Cells(i, 17)).Value
                .Range(10) = wswk.Cells(i, 19)).Value
                .Range(11) = wswk.Cells(i, 20)).Value
            End With
        End If
        Next i

    n = n + 1
    wk = wk + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Can you edit your answer?